# Fluent NHibernate Mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the class filter.cs with this attributes:

```
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
    public virtual Int16 Type { get; set; }
    public virtual string FilterValue { get; set; }
    public virtual ReportConfiguration ReportConfiguration { get; set; }
```

Attribute and ReportConfiguration are a Foreign Key.

I made this mapping:

```
        Id(a => a.Id).UnsavedValue(0).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(a => a.Type);
        Map(a => a.FilterValue);
        References(x => x.ReportConfiguration).Column("IdReportConfiguration").Not.LazyLoad();
        References(x => x.Attribute).Column("IdAttribute").Not.LazyLoad();
```

In addition, I have a Repository class for example with the method:

```
public int Create(Filter F)
    {
        int FilterId = 0;
        Transactional(session =>
        {
            FilterId = (int)session.Save(F);
        });
        return FilterId;
    }
```

And when I did the Unit Test of `Create(Filter F)` it produced an exception:

No persister for: ....Filter.cs

I think the mapping is not correct.

Any idea?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try here:

[Fluent Nhibernate No persister for:](http://weblogs.asp.net/chanderdhall/archive/2010/09/09/no-persister-for-lt-classname-gt.aspx)

From the above post:

> Solution: This error occurs since the class is not public. Just change
>   the class to public and this won't occur again. However, if you do not
>   want to expose the assembly outside the Assembly you can still mark
>   the constructor as 'internal'.

Is this your situation?

---

This is a similar question:

[Fluent Nhibernate No Persistor for Class Name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3677900/735864)

Comment: Perfect I do my Class public.